# setting CURL's return code as a variable in Batch

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have seen some people using a for loop but I do not think that executes the curl command. If it does please let me know. right now I am using the code below but it does not seem to be putting the return code into the text file. Also it would be really nice if it put it as a variable instead of the text file

I have tried

```
curl -k -F key_file=@%curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%.key -F cert_file=@%curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%.cer https://%PDUUser%:%CurlPass%@%PDUIP%/cgi-bin/server_ssl_cert_upload.cgi -w %curfileloc%\test.txt
```

But that outputs nothing to the text file
I have also tried

```
curl -k -F key_file=@%curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%.key -F cert_file=@%curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%.cer https://%PDUUser%:%CurlPass%@%PDUIP%/cgi-bin/server_ssl_cert_upload.cgi>> %curfileloc%\test.txt
```

That will out put the return code to the text file but not the device name (%PDUname%)

I would really like to get it set as a variable in batch so that I can use that to preform other actions.

What I hope to get is something like

curl -k -F key_file=@%curfileloc%\devices%PDUName%%PDUName%.key -F cert_file=@%curfileloc%\devices%PDUName%%PDUName%.cer https://%PDUUser%:%CurlPass%@%PDUIP%/cgi-bin/server_ssl_cert_upload.cgi -w %curfileloc%\test.txt

To be set as set CurlReturn=%1 and then have that either log the result with something like

echo %PUDname% %CurlReturn%>> Curllog.txt Or to try running the command again

Comment: What's wrong with `(Echo=%PDUName%` followed by `curl...) 1>"%curfileloc%\test.txt"`, or `(Set /P "=%PDUName% " 0<NUL` followed by `curl...) 1>"%curfileloc%\test.txt"`.

Comment: The issue I see is that if the file transfer is successful Curl outputs "Return code = 0". But if it fails then it outputs 3 lines

<HTML>
<HTML> 401 unauthorized /n <HTML>
<HTML> 401 unauthorized <HTML><HTML>

I tried using %errorlevel% "do something" but %errorlevel% is always 0

one workaround that seems to be working is ending the curl command with >C:\some file.txt to put the output into a text file then using 

Find /I (the text file from above) "401 unauthorized /n" ( do something || ( do something else )

That way if it fails then "401 unauthorized /n" will be there

Comment: No I get how they work and yes I have read the documentation, but your need to try to call people ignorant when what you suggest does not seem to work is telling. I am not saying I know everything either. The command I am running is 
'
curl -k -F key_file=@%curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%.key -F cert_file=@%curfileloc%\devices\%PDUName%\%PDUName%.cer https://%PDUUser%:%CurlPass%1@%PDUIP%/cgi-bin/server_ssl_cert_upload.cgi -f -o %curfileloc%\C.txt
'

The issue is like I said before the output file only states "return_code=0" even though it failed because I made the password wrong

Comment: Although the message on the CMD screen does say it failed on code 22.

But if I take the `-f` out then I get 

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/loose.dtd">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Error</TITLE>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Authorization required</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```